# Getting the i_th value of a vector merged into tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `tibble` that I want to add a column to. The `tibble` can be of any length n where it is the outcome of three variables:

```r
x <- 1:5 # can be any sequence length
u <- 3L # can be any integer
data_length <- length(x)
h <- 3L # can be any integer
```

The function will take the above and spit out a `tibble` that is 45 long: `data_length * u * h`

Now I also have a vector `nt` that is made by `nt <- seq(from = 1, to = length(x) + 1 - 1/u, by = 1/u)` and in this case will give the following:

```r
[1] 1.000000 1.333333 1.666667 2.000000 2.333333 2.666667 3.000000 3.333333 3.666667 4.000000
[11] 4.333333 4.666667 5.000000 5.333333 5.666667
```

I want to be able to make a `tibble` of the following:

```r
nt  | x | h 
-----------
1   | 1 | 1
1.3 | 0 | 1
1.6 | 0 | 1
2   | 2 | 1
2.3 | 0 | 1
... |...|...
5   | 5 | 1
... |...|...
1   | 1 | 3
1.3 | 0 | 3
1.6 | 0 | 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)

replicate(h, tibble(nt) %>%
  mutate(x = replace(nt, -seq(1, n(), u), 0)), simplify = FALSE) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'h')

# A tibble: 45 x 3
#    h         nt     x
#   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1     1          1
# 2 1     1.3333     0
# 3 1     1.6667     0
# 4 1     2          2
# 5 1     2.3333     0
# 6 1     2.6667     0
# 7 1     3          3
# 8 1     3.3333     0
# 9 1     3.6667     0
#10 1     4          4
# … with 35 more rows
```